# How to convert a Wordpress mysql DB to UTF8?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've had my self hosted Wordpress blog for a long time. I just realized that my DB is not UTF8 and certain plugins won't work correctly.

My question is this. How does a very novice mysql'er go about converting my database? As you can imagine, I'm very hesitant to do this on my own as I have 5 years worth of posts I don't want to jack up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or even better step me through the process for converting everything to UTF8?

Comment: First step: backup your database.

Answer (score 2):

After backing up your database as Konerak said, run this for every table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

(you may want to check with `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename` whether all (text)columns are now indeed corrrect)

And right after you connect to MySQL, run the query:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Now, to tell your audience you are using utf8: you could craft a custom header in every page or in an always included file, I however find it easier to put this in an `.htaccess` for Apache in the root:

```
php_value default_charset "UTF-8"
```

If you have non-ASCII content in flat files instead of only in the database, you'll have to convert them too. Your favorite editor may have a batch convert tool, or you can use `iconv`.

Comment: Ack, indeed, if the OP wants to use utf-8 anywhere that would save a lot of work in future.